# How to add image between blog posts

Tags: css, wordpress, toolbox

I'm trying to figure out how to add an image between blog posts (i.e., a graphic basic divider line, not a border) on my website: www.sacspartans.org

I know how to create and div, add the image, etc.  But I don't know what file to make the modification to.  Does anybody know?

I'm using Toolbox, the bare bones starter theme.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I opened up the index file... but I'm not sure where to add my div.

Comment: You're going to have to supply more information than that. Are you just trying to add some HTML to a template file? Post some code if possible.

Comment: Got it figured out.  Just add the div right above '<?php endwhile; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the div right above `<?php endwhile; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Make it so that the three divs are like this:

```
<div class="div">
//blogpost 1
</div>

<div class="div">
//pic
</div>

<div class="div">
//blogpost 2
</div>
```

CSS

```
.div {
float: left;
display: inline;
//rest of css
}
```